# How to find the name of the text file processing in textstreaming in Spark on HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, spark-streaming

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("Multiple text files in single text file")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3600))
     val data = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://bigopeclu/user/z022897/Streaming/")
data.foreach{



}
```

I want to get the file at each instance which it is processing currently

Comment: Don't think it's possible with `textFileStream` but you can use `wholeTextFiles` which returns the filename and its content as a `PairRDD`

Comment: I Have to use textFileStream because i want to track from which file name data came

Comment: Can you not do that with `wholeTextFiles`? Reason is it returns the filename and its content so you can keep track of the name of the file from which the data came.

Comment: We cannot use StreamingContent with wholeTextFiles